# VS Code shortcut to stage changes in toggled elements of list

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

I would like to add a shortcut to stage changes in all files "toggled" in the SCM pane of VS Code. The behavior should be the same as if I clicked on the plus icon of a particular file having multiple files toggled (see picture):

[image]

I have set the following keybinding so far:

```
{
    "key": "cmd+enter",
    "command": "git.stage",
    "when": "listFocus && sideBarFocus && activeViewlet == 'workbench.view.scm'"
}
```

This does not work properly. It stages only a file that was in the last focused editor, ignoring the selection made in Changes.

Any ideas on how I could fix my 'when' to make it work?

Just for context, I would like to be able to stage a selected list of files in Change using only the keyboard.

Thanks!

Comment: do you want to stage all changed files?

Comment: No, all files that are "selected" (toggled) in the treeview. In the pic it would correspond to .upload.sh, .deploy.sh and Button.test.jsx (but not .gitignore)

Answer (score 4):

I found a way of doing it only by using keyboard, but it require few more steps:

1. `Shift + ctrl +g ,g` -> to focus on SCM window
2. Then holding `shift` select files with arrows
3. Then press `tab` , you should see highlight like below:
   [image]
4. Then you can move to `+` button with right arrow and press `enter`:
   [image]

Comment: lame, microsoft!  :)